# Play To does not appear on context menu

Tags: windows-8, dlna

It's weird, I have 2 pc connected to the same network, both win 8, from my laptop I can right click on any media file and I always can see the menu called "play to" to stream the content to my TV, and it works, but on the other PC I don't see this shortcut when I click a media file.

Well, sometimes it appears, but most of times it doesnt.

I don't have any idea, how can I troubleshoot ?

Comment: Just to point out, from the not working pc, I can see my media TV listed on the network, and if I click on its icon it shows me its properties, but anyway the "play to" shortcut does not appear on windows explorer.